# Compound subjects

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

When we use more than one subject in the sentence and compound them with "***or***" and "***and***" the verb will be singular or plural?

For example:

> Red bricks *or* stone ***is / are*** all we have for sale.
>
> Blood, sweat, and tears ***goes / go*** into this.
>
> Connie or Julie ***are / is*** coming over.

and also about this sentence that is from "Understanding and using Grammar":

1-Chicken, duck, and turkey lay eggs.

or

2-chickens,ducks, and turkeys lay eggs.

I think the first sentence is correct because chicken, duck and turkey together become 3 animal and using the verb **lay** is correct. If I'm wrong please explain it.

thank you

Comment: A group of several different things takes a plural verb, unless the verb refers to only one of them _Connie and Julie are coming_, but _Either Connie or Julie is coming_. Your sentence (1) is not correct. You could say _The chicken, the duck and the turkey are all creatures which lay eggs_.

Comment: I disagree. Lots of native speakers (not sure if it's the *majority* or not, without further research) routinely assign the plurality of ***X and Y*** to be the plurality of ***Y*** (the most recently mentioned item in the "list"). So OP's first example is perfectly valid to them (including me), just as is *Stone or red bricks **are** all we have in stock* if we resequence to put the manifestly plural item last in the list.

Comment: ...see [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=name+and+address+is+required%2Cname+and+address+are+required&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that over the past 80 years, "name and address **are** required" has ***usually*** (but not ***always***) been more common in writing than "name and address **is** required". There might sometimes be differences in exact context, but the bottom line is both versions are in common use, and they (often? usually?) mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: I agree with Kate. There are exceptions where a plural verb is used but those are exceptions. The second sentence has a plural subject due to the *and* so *go* must be used. Bro, together we've answered THREE questions. You're only supposed to ask ONE.